# Como puedo actualizar mi array en un archivo Json con java

Tags: java

Tengo una clase Uusario elcual almacena los campos requeridos y un main en el cual te pide entre otras cosas, la opcion de registro, en la cual opera en funcion de que exista el archivo previamente o no.

En el primer caso, funciona sin problemas, ya que crea un array de un unico objeto con los datos. Sin embargo, en el momento ingresamos ala misma opcion nuevamente, detecta que ya existe un archivo y l oque deseo es o bien actualizar el array colocando el objeto nuevo antes del ultimo elemento ("]"), o bien sustituirlo por el susodicho de forma que tuviera una estructura similar a la siguiente:

```
[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"}]
```

a esta...

```
[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"}
,{"key4":"value4","key5":"value5","key6":"value6"}]
```

Este seria el codigo fundamental

```
public static void signUp() {// add user
        String path = "E:\\src\\users.json";

        User new_user = new User();//new user's instance
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter data: ");
        System.out.println("==================");
        String id = generateUserId() ;
        System.out.println("Enter your email: ");
        String emailUser = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter your password: ");
        String passwordUser = ingressPassword();
        System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
        String nameUser = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter your second name: ");
        String second_name_User = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter your age: ");
        int ageUser = scanner.nextInt();

        new_user.setUser_id(id);
        new_user.setEmail(emailUser);
        new_user.setPassword(passwordUser);
        new_user.setName(nameUser);
        new_user.setSecond_name(second_name_User);
        new_user.setAge(ageUser);

        //Test
        //System.out.println(new_user.toString());
        try
        {
            //new file instance at the path
            File file = new File(path);
            //tries to create new file in the system
            boolean bool=file.createNewFile();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file,true));
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String string = "["+jsonArray(new_user);
            if(bool){//if doesn't exists, had been created

                System.out.println("File created. Creating and writing");
                //System.out.println(string);
                writer.write(string,0,string.length());

            }else {//if exists previously
                System.out.println("File created. File created previosuly");
                String response =","+jsonArray(new_user);
                //remove last element

                //append
                writer.newLine();
                writer.append(response,0,
                        response.length());

            }
            writer.write("]");
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static String jsonArray(User user){

        //adding arraylist new element
        String data =
                "{"+
                "\"id:\":"+"\""+user.getUser_id()+"\""+
                ",\"name\":"+"\""+user.getName()+"\"" +
                ",\"second_name\":"+"\""+user.getSecond_name()+"\""+
                ",\"age\":"+"\""+user.getAge()+"\""+
                ",\"email:\":"+"\""+user.getEmail()+"\""+
                ",\"password\":"+"\""+user.getPassword()+"\""
                +"}";
        return data;
    }
```

Comment: No me queda claro que es lo que quieres, si el JSON que muestras es que quieres o el que obtienes.

Comment: El primer modelo de JSON es el que tengo en un primer momento y el segundo seria el mismo archivo actualizado con un segundo registro, siendo este el archivo tras la operacion. Espero haberme explicado bien, gracias.

Comment: Usando Gson (https://github.com/google/gson) lee el archivo y conviertelo en un lista. Luego modificas la lista y vuelves a generar el json y sobreescribes el archvio anterior completo.

Comment: He aplicado esa metodologia y me he topado con un problema inesperado. A la hora de leer un JSON y reescribirlo el primer objeto conserva la lectura de comillas que la lectura le ha dado.[
  {
    "name": "\"1\"",
    "second_name": "\"1\"",
    "age": "\"1\"",
    "email": "\"1\"",
    "user_id": "\"YjyLJJo\"",
    "password": "\"1\""
  },
  {
    "name": "2",
    "second_name": "2",
    "age": "2",
    "email": "2",
    "user_id": "sdmcgdD",
    "password": "2"
  }
]